# how to call getCollection method for a custom table on index controller?

Tags: controllers, magento2.2, resource-model

```
$pincode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('p', false);
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
 $collection = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $collection = $this->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('pincode', array('eq' => $pincode));
            $codData = $collection->getData();

            if($codData[0]['pincode'] != '' && $codData[0]['cod'] != ''){
                echo '<span class="cod-suc">Delivery Available';
                if($codData[0]['days'] != ''){
                    $final = ' within '.$codData[0]['days'].' days <br>'.$codData[0]['cod'].' ';
                }
                echo '.</span>';
            }else{
               $final =  '<span class="cod-error">Delivery Not Available</span>';
            }
```

it always gives this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Pradeep\PincodeChecker\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor::getCollection()

Comment: tell me why you put this $collection = $this->getCollection() line?

Comment: well i am writing code for pincode extension for my site on m2,  have done everything but not able to show msg of COD and days column from table, yet i am able to show pincode status is available, i have put this line for getting db results for fetching directly linkng with sql query with where clause on controller so i can transfer results to desired function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the model collection factory into your constructor

```
protected $collectionFactory;
public function __construct(
....
\[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ResourceModel\[Entity]\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, 
...
)
{
...
$this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
...
}
```

Now you can use collection as:

> $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();